# Angular Http Promise return undefined

Tags: angular, http, typescript, undefined

Just trying to set my component property from a http result but no success. Thank for your help !  (working with a static mock object)

Class - Object

```
export class Gallery {
    name: string;
}
```

---

Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Gallery } from './GalleryModel';


@Injectable()
export class GalleryLoadService {

    private galleryUrl = 'api/Gallery/Get'; 

    constructor(private http: Http) {
    }


    getGalleries(): Promise<Gallery[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.galleryUrl)
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json().data as Gallery[])
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
        console.error('An error occurred', error); 
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }
}
```

---

Component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Gallery } from './GalleryModel';
import { GalleryLoadService } from './gallery-services';


@Component({
    selector: 'my-gallery',
    templateUrl: 'gallery-component.html',
    moduleId: module.id 
})
export class GalleryComponent implements OnInit {
    galleries: Gallery[];

    constructor(private galleryService: GalleryLoadService) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getGals();
    }

    getGals(): void {

        this.galleryService
            .getGalleries()
            .then(gals => {
            this.galleries = gals;
            console.log(this.galleries); <=== TypeError: gals is undefined!!!!!
            });
    }      
}
```

### console.log return TypeError: gals is undefined!!!!!

API call result

```
[{"name":"Cats"},{"name":"Dogs"}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that is the result you get from the API, then you should not be using `response.json().data` in your `getGalleries` method since there is no `data` property. Remove the `data`:

```
.then(response => response.json() as Gallery[])
```

See the [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#parse-to-json):

> Make no assumptions about the server API. Not all servers return an
>   object with a `data` property.

Comment: You made my day ! Thank you !